# Copy data from a selected excel file

Tags: vba, excel, getopenfilename

I am trying to construct a macro that when run will allow me to select a given file and check the data in Column C of that selected file.  I am very new to VBA and have only rudimentary skills.  I have all the parts of my code working except for the portion where I pull in the data from the variable file and paste it into column A of my macro file for the review functions to perform.

I have cobbled together the below code to populate the data from Column C of any given selected file into Column A of the macro file from what I could piece together from searching through the site, but I am still getting an error 400 after selecting the file to open when running this Sub.  Would appreciate any assistance with figuring this portion out.

Thanks!

```
Sub PopulateUploaderFunds()
'Pull in funds from uploader to be reviewed for custody and mirror accounts
Dim uploadfile As Variant
Dim uploader As Workbook
MsgBox ("Please select uploader file to be reviewed")
uploadfile = Application.GetOpenFilename()
If uploadfile = "False" Then
Exit Sub
End If
Workbooks.Open uploadfile
Set uploader = ActiveWorkbook
With uploader
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("C1").End(xlDown).Select
    Selection.Copy
End With
Windows("Test Mirror Macro Build Test.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a problem with how you are navigating between workbooks, try this:

```
Sub PopulateUploaderFunds()
'Pull in funds from uploader to be reviewed for custody and mirror accounts
Dim uploadfile As Variant
Dim uploader As Workbook
Dim CurrentBook As Workbook

Set CurrentBook = ActiveWorkbook
MsgBox ("Please select uploader file to be reviewed")
uploadfile = Application.GetOpenFilename()
    If uploadfile = "False" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
Workbooks.Open uploadfile
Set uploader = ActiveWorkbook
With uploader
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("C:C").Copy
End With
CurrentBook.Activate
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: D_Zab,
Thanks, the error is no longer occuring, but I am not seeing the data from Column C of uploader populating in Column A of CurrentBook after running the Sub.  I've tried grabbing a few different files.  Any thoughts?

Would it matter that I'm trying to get them from excel files that are saved as .csv?

Comment: Yead the `.End(xldown)` part wont work in a csv file so you'd only get the first cell. I modified my answer to just copy the entire column so it should work now.

Comment: Thanks, getting closer.  It looks like that it copying column C of the macro file rather than the .csv file, though.